# .ajax for upload file and send text input to php, showed error message but upload success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I know this is a simple questions for experts here, but it has been bothering me for a few days. I am a beginners, and I think there is some problem in handling the data.

So my purpose here is to both fetched the file uploaded and email input by user, send it to upload.php, and then upload.php will return a reference ID, and then display it to user.

The problem I faced is instead of alert me with the reference number, it will show **two errors**:

> 1. Undefined index fileToUpload in xampp/htdocs...
> 2. There is an error in uploading file

But, the upload file is successful, I can see the uploaded file in my database and reference code is generated successfully.

If this two issues are solve, how can I display the reference code in the HTML part. Thanks!!! Any help is appreciate!

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="main-contact-form" name="main-contact-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email Address">
   <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" value="fileToUpload">
   <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left crsa-selected">
</div>
</form>
```

Here is my .ajax call that going to send email address and uploaded file to upload.php

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#main-contact-form").on('submit',(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: 'upload.php', 
    type: 'post',             
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    async: false,
    success: function()   
    {
    alert("ajax success");
    }
});

function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = function() {
    alert(this.responseText);
};
oReq.open("get", "upload.php", true);
oReq.send();
}));
});
```

This is my upload.php

```
<?php
include("db.php");
$target_dir = "";
$target_file = "";

$target_dir = "submittedform/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$refId = "";
// upload file
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))
    {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded. <br/>";

        $refID = !empty($_POST['refID']) ? $_POST['refID'] : time() . rand(10*45, 100*98);;

        // echo "Reference ID: " . $refID . "<br/>";
        echo json_encode("Reference ID: " . $refID . "<br/>");

        #once file uploaded, the path and reference code will be updated, status will be set to 1
        $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO student(reference_id, upload_appli_form, status) VALUES ('$refID', '$target_file', '1')";
        $qInsert = mysqli_query($db, $sqlInsert) or die("Error : ". mysqli_error($qInsert));

    }

    else
    {
        echo json_encode("Sorry, there was an error uploading your file. <br/>");
    }   

    mysqli_close($db);

?>
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: `async: false` is deprecated and will call an error soon

Comment: and why do you use `var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();` if you already used `$.ajax();`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it must be simpler? Like this?

And now it's async. So it will be valid for years :D

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#main-contact-form").on('submit', (function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php', 
            type: 'post',             
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false                
        }).done(function(result) {
            alert(result); //your POST answer
        });
    }));
});
```